# Process mailbody with SSIS

Tags: ssis, exchange-server, business-intelligence

I'm working on a SSIS project that mainly fetches data from an oracle DB and puts it in excel sheets, with some logging and email-sending etc.

Situation now: comments are emailed daily and manually copy pasted from outlook into the excel files (oldskool)

Now, we'd like to fetch the (whole) <'body'> of the emails and insert that in excel via SSIS.

2 questions arise: 
-- How to fetch the mail itself (fetch it from the exchange? create a process that saves the mail as a html/text file after receiving)
-- How to 'read' the body of the email (I already found some info on this, less of a problem, via a C# script task read the body tag)

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use 3rd party components to read messages from Exchange.

It's better to try Script Task to access Exchange (take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447413/get-inbox-message-from-exchange-server-using-net)). This way You can access exchange mailbox and put subject, from, to, cc, bcc and body in separate columns in pipeline. Don't forget that connecting to Exchange requires windows account and that way your package must be run by user who owns mailbox. Or You can impersonate him in Script Task.

Since this is quite a task, U guess it would be better to create simple application that will read mails and store them in database so You can retrieve them easily with SSIS.

Comment: thanks, indeed we'll try to fetch the mails and store them in the DB first outside SSIS. Otherwise it's too complicated via exchange